# Keeping only certain elements inside html with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to keep only certain elements that has been added to a text area using jQuery. I'm using MutationObserver to find any new items added to a div and copy that to the form.

```
// passes content to the string, new items are also found
// and added using the MutationObserver
//
var stringContent = $("#OriginalOutput").html()
```

But, in this case I'm looking to get all the new 'li' found in the html.

I tried some methods like this for example:

```
var stringContent = $("#OriginalOutput").clone().find('.container')
  .insertAfter().end().html();
```

this works but only give me the first 'li' element inside. I also tried other ways replacing insertAfter with something else that left me with the same result, but not giving all the 'li' elements it finds.

I already have the ul element being called somewhere else, and i just need to pass all the 'li' elements found into the string. This way I can use it on here:

```
//edited from #OriginalOutput to #output
$("#output").val("<ul class=\"mylist\">\n" + stringContent + "</ul>");
```

Another method i tried was removing the elements i didn't needed just to keep all the 'li' that's been added, but the problem I was having was i didn't know how to remove each class and if i remove the parent div that's holding all the elements, it would just take everything inside it including the 'li' elements, so I'm sure I can't do that. Although I did try to get it out using PHP with str_replace on the final output, but was able to get only certain elements out since most of the elements i need to remove outputs unique ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.each()` function.  If you're only getting one element delivered, this may help.  Change your jQuery to look like this:

```
var stringContent = '';
$("#OriginalOutput").clone().find('li').each(function(){
  var t = $(this);
  stringContent += t[0].outerHTML;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Per asker's comments:

My guess is then that your problem isn't to do with pulling the items, but rather with putting them in.  I'd change the way you're inserting them to this:

```
$("#OriginalOutput").clone().find('li').each(function(){
  var t = $(this);
  $("#OriginalOutput").append(t);
});
```

I'm not sure why you'd chosen `val()` in the original answer, I just assumed that `$('#OriginalOutput')` was a hidden element.  If it is a hidden element, you might want to construct a clone from scratch in your function, like this:

```
var myCloneElement = $(document.createElement('ul'));
myCloneElement = $('#myTargetList').clone();
$("#OriginalOutput").clone().find('li').each(function(){
  var t = $(this);
  myCloneElement.append(t);
});
$('#myTargetList').html(myCloneElement.html());
```

Comment: Yes, I'm only getting one element delivered from the #OriginalOutput even though I know its getting updated. Leaving it as $("#OriginalOutput").html() will return everything inside including all the li elements, even when I post the form I have everything. I'm sure i need some kind of solution using each, but I tried what you have there and didn't work for me.

Comment: The items are being pulled already from an uploader, it updates the #OriginalOutput, im copying the contents from the #OriginalOutput to a text area which i had a id with #output. I'm not sure if somebody updated my question or my mistake, but the last block code needs to be #output Here's an example of what i have working that outputs all the content to the area, even when it updates: http://jsfiddle.net/4cwv6/

Comment: Josh, I made a couple changes to fit what you have and it works now. Using the last block of code you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked Alex! Thanks for the clear question and helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var stringContent = $("#OriginalOutput .container").clone().find(':not(li)')
    .remove().end().html();
```

Comment: Gladly!  That's why I'm here.

Comment: I did put the end() back in. I think that's needed to return to the original element.

Comment: Thanks guys! The last edit only returned one li element and not all. But I also noticed it removed everything inside the li element, like the title and link that needs to output on each.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. We're not doing anything with the LI tags in this code.